# How to improve Python code to show widgets

Tags: tkinter, pycharm, widget, python-3.8

Python code uses tkinter, compiled by PyCharm-Community, shows only empty Application Form, without widgets on it. 
PyCharm informed about compiled code:

> Process finished with exit code 0

Below is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()

# create the application
app = Application()
app.master.title("Sumator")
app.master.minsize(width=640, height=96)

# start the program
app.mainloop()

def __init__(self, master=None):
    super().__init__(master)
    self.pack()
    self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        # create widgets
        self.firstNumberEntry = tk.Entry()
        self.plusSign = tk.Label(text="+")
        self.secondNumberEntry = tk.Entry()
        self.equalSign = tk.Label(text="=")
        self.resultLabel = tk.Label(text="Result...", bg="green", fg="white")
        self.calculateButton = tk.Button(text="Calculate")
        # place widgets
        self.firstNumberEntry.pack(side="left")
        self.plusSign.pack(side="left")
        self.secondNumberEntry.pack(side="left")
        self.resultLabel.pack(side="left")
        self.calculateButton.pack(side="left")

        tk.Button(text="Calculate", command=self.calculate)
        def calculate(self):
            first_value = float(self.firstNumberEntry.get())
            second_value = float(self.secondNumberEntry.get())
            result = first_value + second_value
            self.resultLabel.config(text=str(result), bg="green", fg="white")
```

How to improve code, to show widgets and to work with them?

Comment: Is this your actual code, in the order that is in your file?

Comment: This is exactly my actual code, that is in my file.

Comment: May be it is good, to mention, that I am absolutely beginner with Python, PyCharm and Tkinter. This is my first attempt to use GUI widgets. ( Until now I have only 6 simple examples by Pyton and PyCharm, but without using GUI widgets. )

Comment: As an improvement I moved the starting of the code to its end ....